# how to get Many2one field depends on Many2many field?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-10

On my module i need that when i select travels, the departure(**departure_id**) and destination(**arrival_id**) of selected travels appear. Any help please? i'm stuck with issue for days now

tms_travel_planning.py

```
travel_ids = fields.Many2many('tms.travel','tms_planning_tms_travel_rel','tms_planning_id','tms_travel_id','travel_ids')
```

tms_travel_planning.xml

```
<field name="travel_ids" widget="many2many_checkboxes"/>
```

tms_travel.py

```
 departure_id = fields.Many2one('tms.place',string='Departure',compute='_compute_departure_id',store=True,readonly=True)
 arrival_id = fields.Many2one('tms.place',string='Arrival',compute='_compute_arrival_id',store=True,readonly=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using both @api.onchange('travel_ids') and @api.constrains('travel_ids')?  I've found that I sometimes have to use both to get it to visually change, and save the change.